# Proof by induction for all positive integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, induction

$\sum_{j=1}^n j^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n + 1)}{6}$

So I did the obvious and plugged one to show that

$1^2 = \frac{1(1+1)(2(1) + 1)}{6}$

Now I am trying to show that

$1^2 + 2^2 + ... + n^2 + (n + 1)^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n + 1)}{6} + (n +1)$

By simplifying the expression on the right I have gotten stuck at

$\frac{(n + 1)(2n^2 + n + 6)}{6}$

So either I have done the completely wrong thing, but I can see no way to get to

$\frac{(n + 1)((n + 1) + 1)(2(n + 1) + 1)}{6}$

Comment: You added $n+1$, not $(n+1)^2$.

Comment: I am going to lie in a ball and cry now...

Comment: No need to, since if you use $(n+1)^2$, you will get $\frac{(n+1)(2n^2+7n+6)}{6}$, and the quadratic factors nicely.

Comment: Thanks :) I want to cry because I stared at this for over an hour and did not realize that I missed the exponent

Comment: Minor glitches are a fact of life. You had the *structure* of the argument right.

Comment: That is the sort of mistake you either spot immediately, or need to be pointed out (or you can set it aside for a while and then look at it again, then you might also spot it yourself).